# Compute a summation with limit log

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, logarithms

I want to compute the summation of

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor{\log(n)}\rfloor{}}{i}
$$

I could not find an axiom to solve it. thank!

Comment: your upper bound is not a natural number. Do you mean $\lfloor{\log(n)}\rfloor$? Anyway, in general there is the formula $1+2+3+...+M = \sum_{i=1}^M = M(M+1)/2$.

Comment: Thank, it was edited! Your serie it not usefull for me, I need to solve it.

Comment: Just substitute $\lfloor \log (n) \rfloor$ for $M$ in what @Simon said and you are done.

Comment: Okk.. thank,.. I understand!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See that

[image]

In other words,

$$2(1+2+3+\dots+n)=n(n+1)$$

$$1+2+3+\dots+n={n(n+1)\over2}$$

So, plugging our stuff in, we have

$$1+2+3+\dots+\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor={\lfloor\log(n)\rfloor\lfloor1+\log(n)\rfloor\over2}$$